# regex to find optional suffixes in name

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to find optional suffixes from the below pattern

Doe, John (JR) (IV) - suffix1 is JR and suffix 2 is IV

Doe, John (JR)  - suffix 1 is JR and siffix 2 is empty

Doe, John  - Both suffix1 and suffix 2 are empty

I have tried the below approach to find the suffix

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches("Doe, John (JR) (IV)", @"(.*?)\s*(?:\(.*?\))?\s*(?:\(.*?\))?$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var name = matches[0].Groups[1].Value;
var suff1 = matches[0].Groups[2].Value;
var suff2 = matches[0].Groups[3].Value;
```

but suff1 and suff2 are empty. what am I doing wrong in the regex and is there any better approach to find the values within parenthesis instead of using regex

Comment: You only have one capturing group in your pattern. If you want a regex, try [`(.+?)\s*(?:\((.+?)\))?\s*(?:\((.+?)\))?$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(.%2b%3f)%5cs*(%3f%3a%5c((.%2b%3f)%5c))%3f%5cs*(%3f%3a%5c((.%2b%3f)%5c))%3f%24&i=my+name+(534)+(767)) where each group requires at least 1 symbol.

Comment: Are there any other rules about names and prefixes? The more constrained they are the easier it will be to make a pattern that matches. For example, is it possible to have spaces in the last name? is it possible to have spaces in the first name? Is it possible to have a suffix with parentheses? Like would this be a valid name: `Last Name, First Name (Suffix (1)) (Suffix (2))`? Are last name and first name **always** present?

Comment: So, what are the requirements and what is the expected output?

Comment: I was simply looking for a way to capture the value of suffixes from the parenthesis.  I have missed the matching groups for suffix1 and suffix2. Fixed the regex as @"(.*?)\s*(\(.*?\))?\s*(\(.*?\))?$" Thank you guys !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not enough information here to be sure that this will for you in all cases, but based on the information that you have given, this will work. Depending on the information that you have not given, this may not work.

`(.+?)(?:\s*\((.+?)\))?(?:\s*\((.+?)\))?$`